# Unable to match regex in C

Tags: c, regex

I have a problem with following regex:

```
 prefix:\w+,\w+,\s*-?[0-9]{1,4}\s*,\s*-?[0-9]{1,4}\s*,\s*-?[0-9]{1,4}\s*,(?:\w+)
```

The match string is the following:

```
prefix:string,string,-100,100,0,string
```

I cannot match this string in my C code. At least I get a successful match on some online [tool](https://regex101.com/r/4yVSOH/2) where I generated this regex. Also there were compilation warnings about "\" characters in regex so I replaced it as explained in [c-compiler-warning-unknown-escape-sequence-using-regex-for-c-program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477153/c-compiler-warning-unknown-escape-sequence-using-regex-for-c-program). Regex after compilation warning fixes:

```
prefix:\\w+,\\w+,\\s*-?[0-9]{1,4}\\s*,\\s*-?[0-9]{1,4}\\s*,\\s*-?[0-9]{1,4}\\s*,(?:\\w+)
```

Here's the testing code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>        
#include <stdlib.h>

#define REGEX "prefix:\\w+,\\w+,\\s*-?[0-9]{1,4}\\s*,\\s*-?[0-9]{1,4}\\s*,\\s*-?[0-9]{1,4}\\s*,(?:\\w+)"

const char *input = "prefix:string,string,-100,100,0,string";
int main(){

    int rc;

    regex_t regex;

    rc = regcomp(&regex, REGEX, 0);
    if (rc != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    rc = regexec(&regex, input, 0, NULL, 0);
    if (rc == 0) {
        printf("Match!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else if (rc == REG_NOMATCH) {
        printf("No match\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        perror("Error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I use gcc version 6.2.0 20161005 (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12)

Comment: As this looks like a fairly complicated regex, you may need `REG_EXTENDED`: "The default regular expression type for pattern is a Basic Regular Expression. The application can specify Extended Regular Expressions using the REG_EXTENDED cflags flag." (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/regcomp.html)

Comment: `REG_EXTENDED` must be used if the limiting quantifier is not escaped. In BRE, the `{n,m}` should  be escaped. I also think the `(?:)` should be removed. See [this C demo](https://ideone.com/XhrX8h) returning `Match`.

Comment: @RadLexus I tried it, regcomp fails with this flag specified in cflags argument

Comment: This is weird. Even a simple regex, such as `.{4}` and an input of `aaaa` fails to match. I'm look at the man pages and I see nothing wrong with your code at face value...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is right. Good catch on the `REG_EXTENDED`.

Comment: @Qix: It is not only `REG_EXTENDED` that is important. POSIX regex does not "know" non-capturing groups.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes `(?:` replacement with `(` worked, I didn't mention it but the last string is optional, that's why the regex differs for it. Also the REG_EXTENDED is required for it to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to do two things:

- Use `REG_EXTENDED` flag to compile the regex (so that extended regular expression flavor (ERE) is enabled), else the limiting quantifier will need escaping, and there may be other potential issues
- Remove the non-capturing group `(?:...)` as POSIX does not support this construct.
- To make `\w+` optional, just replace `(?:\w+)` with `\w*`.

Use

```
#define REGEX "prefix:\\w+,\\w+,\\s*-?[0-9]{1,4}\\s*,\\s*-?[0-9]{1,4}\\s*,\\s*-?[0-9]{1,4}\\s*,\\w*"
                                                                                                ^^^
```

and then

```
rc = regcomp(&regex, REGEX, REG_EXTENDED);
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [C demo](https://ideone.com/XhrX8h).

Also, see more about the [Extended Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04) that are enabled by `REG_EXTENDED`, and [POSIX Bracket Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) is also a good resource to learn differences between BRE (Basic Regular Expressions) and ERE flavors.

Comment: Some links to relevant documentation would be helpful, as always :)

Comment: Hm, yes, just in the [Extended Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04), it is not stated that the non-capturing groups are not supported and that to use `{1,3}` rather than `\{1,3\}` one should use `REG_EXTENDED` flag.

Comment: I added some links and fixed the demo link.