# get rid of regex compilerwarning without using "#include <regex.h>"

Tags: c, regex, vxworks

I am using regex under vxworks and have no possibility to include "regex.h".

I am getting the compilerwarning "unrecognized character escape sequence" for the code `if (sscanf(token, "%*[^\[][%d]", &idx) != 1)`
because of the '\' and the following '['.

Is there a possibility to get rid of that compilerwarning without using the regex.h and stuff like it is done here: [Unable to match regex in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41740157/unable-to-match-regex-in-c)

Comment: `scanf` doesn't use regular expressions. A single format specifier kind of *reminds* of a regex, but it's not. See e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for more details about the `"%["` format specifier.

Comment: The "format" of `scanf()` is **not** a regular expression.

Comment: ... and even if it *were* a regular expression, to include a literal backslash in a string literal you would still need to escape it by doubling it.  Your failure to do so is what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: ok, thanks for pointing to the actual problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try something like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char buf[99];
    int idx, n;
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0; // remove ENTER
        if (sscanf(buf, "%*[^[][%d%n", &idx, &n) != 1) {
            printf("no number in %s\n", buf);
        } else {
            printf("number found: %d (left over string: \"%s\")\n", idx, buf + n);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[See code running on ideone](https://ideone.com/gC2G4m)